# Delphi XE - File Deleted Notification Event:

Tags: delphi, winapi, events, directory, delphi-xe

I need to delete a physical file on a server via a client action, then notify a remote database of the file deletion event - would like this to happen entirely on serverSide.

Later versions of Delphi have exposed a lot of directory services that previously had been locked away in WinAPI calls. Currently I'm using Delphi XE but I'm not up to speed on all the new features (migrated from Delphi 7...)

Is there an event of some kind  in the Delphi XE file/directory services that I can grab on the server side when a file is deleted, so I can notify interested parties of the delete event?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you can find a unit called: [`IOSys`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/IOUtils)

It contains lots of stuff to play with folders and files. But there's no notification included.

You still need to use the function: [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 for taking a shot at it - thanks. But I put up the question because offhand I didn't find anything in IOSys. :-) I know about FindFirstChangeNotification etc - didn't want to do that much work - seems like we should be beyond straight WinAPI by now... But I have a workaround. In fact I'll accept your answer and close the question.

Comment: And what is your workaround? (please, not a timer with a diff ;o))

Comment: No - no timers or polling - I wrote a server call that deletes the file and then updates the database in one pass. Client makes the server call - doesn't interact with the directory at all (better design anyhow - just was a pain to wire it up because it all runs through a dll that didn't know about the app server - until now...)